# Active CSS animation only when you scroll on the view of the specific div

Tags: javascript, html, css, hidden

I have a chart made in CSS and HTML, in this chart there is an animation for the chart loading. I want to start this animation only when I scroll on the view of the div that contain the chart.

I want to charge the chart only when I'm on it on the page, I know that I have to use javascript but I'm a very beginner in JS so I don't know if it is possible to do something like that.

This is the fiddle of the chart:

https://jsfiddle.net/matteous1/pdL0kbqk/

HTML

```
<ul class="chart">
  <li>
    <span style="height:5%; background: rgba(0, 102, 255, 0.80);" title="ActionScript"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:70%; background: rgba(204, 51, 51, 0.80);" title="JavaScript"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:50%; background: rgba(255, 186, 2, 0.80);" title="CoffeScript"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:75%; background: rgba(0, 153, 102, 0.80);" title="HTML"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:90%; background: rgba(0, 102, 255, 0.80);" title="HTML"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:15%; background: rgba(204, 51, 51, 0.80);" title="HTML"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:40%; background: rgba(255, 186, 2, 0.80);" title="HTML"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:55%; background: rgba(0, 153, 102, 0.80);" title="HTML"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.chart {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  /*max-width: 700px;*/
  height: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 2%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 2%);
  background-size: 100% 50px;
  background-position: left top;
}
.chart li {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 200px;
}
.chart span {
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: block;
  /*background: rgba(209, 236, 250, 0.75);*/
  animation: draw 1s ease-in-out;
}
.chart span:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 5px 1em 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: attr(title);
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use onscroll event and check if the element is in viewport

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var charElem = document.querySelector('.chart');

    var isVisible = false;
    window.onscroll = function() {
      if(isElementInViewport(charElem) && !isVisible) {
        charElem.className += " anim";
        isVisible = true;
      }
    }

    function isElementInViewport (el) {

        //special bonus for those using jQuery
        if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
            el = el[0];
        }

        var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

        return (
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
        );
    }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/pdL0kbqk/1/

Note: element in viewport code is reference from this link [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Comment: You can also use some type of in-view plugin. There are many.

Comment: @sheriffderek: Yes initially i thought of writing the answer using jquery and include such references. But I am not sure whether OP is using jquery.

Comment: This solution is perfect but I don't know why it doesn't work on my website

Comment: You probably don't have the DOM loaded first (like, the page hasn't been read when the JS runs)

Comment: if you are using jquery then include my snippet inside dom.ready, if no jquery then create document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false);  call everything inside this handler

Comment: @Matteo: Updated my answer with dom ready listener. Hope it helps

Comment: I tried to put your code but nothing changed, maybe there is some conflict with the other code or I don't know. I included jquery with: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script> plus your code. It should work right?

Comment: @Matteo: if you have jquery in your stack then replace this document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() , with $(document).ready(function()